# Show all matched pairs in a single dataframe - Python Record Linkage

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, record-linkage

I have a pandas MultiIndex object :

```
In [0]: index
Out[0]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[1, 2, 3, 8], [10, 11]],
       labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

This MultiIndex object defines the following 8 pairs :
(1,10),
(1,11),
(2,10),
(2,11),
(3,10),
(3,11),
(8,10),
(8,11).

The elements listed in the levels correspond to the index of a DataFrame:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
     col_1   col_2
0        0       1
1        2       3
2        4       5
3        6       7
4        8       9
5       10      11
6       12      13
7       14      15
8       16      17
9       18      19
10      20      21
11      22      23
```

What I would like is to create a new DataFrame that shows all the pairs defined above. Something that look like:

```
In [2]: result
Out[2]: 
    col_1   col_2     pair
        2       3        0
       20      21        0
        2       3        1
       22      23        1
        4       5        2
       20      21        2
        4       5        3
       22      23        3
        6       7        4
       20      21        4
        6       7        5
       22      23        5
       16      17        6
       20      21        6
       16      17        7
       22      23        7
```

Is there any efficient way to implement this? (if possible, without for-loops)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `stack` with `iloc` or `reindex`

```
df.iloc[m.to_frame().stack()].assign(key=m.to_frame().reset_index(drop=True).stack().index.get_level_values(0))
Out[205]: 
    col_1  col_2  key
1       2      3    0
10     20     21    0
1       2      3    1
11     22     23    1
2       4      5    2
10     20     21    2
2       4      5    3
11     22     23    3
3       6      7    4
10     20     21    4
3       6      7    5
11     22     23    5
8      16     17    6
10     20     21    6
8      16     17    7
11     22     23    7
```

Answer (score 3):

#### `pd.concat`

Not necessarily the most efficient... but clever (-:

```
pd.concat(
    [df.loc[[*pair]].assign(pair=i) for i, pair in enumerate(index)]
).reset_index(drop=True)

    col_1  col_2  pair
0       2      3     0
1      20     21     0
2       2      3     1
3      22     23     1
4       4      5     2
5      20     21     2
6       4      5     3
7      22     23     3
8       6      7     4
9      20     21     4
10      6      7     5
11     22     23     5
12     16     17     6
13     20     21     6
14     16     17     7
15     22     23     7
```

---

#### `zip`

Similar to above

```
i_s, j_s = zip(*[(i, j) for j, p in enumerate(index) for i in p])
df.loc[[*i_s]].assign(pair=j_s).reset_index(drop=True)


    col_1  col_2  pair
0       2      3     0
1      20     21     0
2       2      3     1
3      22     23     1
4       4      5     2
5      20     21     2
6       4      5     3
7      22     23     3
8       6      7     4
9      20     21     4
10      6      7     5
11     22     23     5
12     16     17     6
13     20     21     6
14     16     17     7
15     22     23     7
```

Answer (score 2):

***Setup***

```
m = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[1, 2, 3, 8], [10, 11]],
       labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

---

You can operate on the underlying `numpy` array

```
a = np.stack(m.values)
v = df.values
res = v[a]
c = res.shape[-1]

u = pd.DataFrame(res.reshape(-1, df.shape[1]), columns=df.columns)
u['pair'] = np.repeat(np.arange(u.shape[0] // c), c)
```

```
    col_1  col_2  pair
0       2      3     0
1      20     21     0
2       2      3     1
3      22     23     1
4       4      5     2
5      20     21     2
6       4      5     3
7      22     23     3
8       6      7     4
9      20     21     4
10      6      7     5
11     22     23     5
12     16     17     6
13     20     21     6
14     16     17     7
15     22     23     7
```

---

***Explanation***

When we index the values of the DataFrame using all the combinations of the `MultiIndex`, not only do we get the correct mappings, we get the grouped rows together in a dimension of the output.  We can use the shape from this to infer the `pair` column later.

```
print(v[a])
```

```
array([[[ 2,  3],
        [20, 21]],

       [[ 2,  3],
        [22, 23]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [20, 21]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [22, 23]],

       [[ 6,  7],
        [20, 21]],

       [[ 6,  7],
        [22, 23]],

       [[16, 17],
        [20, 21]],

       [[16, 17],
        [22, 23]]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I got the following error with this solution : 
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index